# "Цена от" в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Как реализовать вывод цены товара в виде "Цена от 299 руб/м2"? Не нашел такой возможности в woocommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте вариативный товар, задайте ему несколько вариаций, установите цену для них.

В function.php добавьте следующий код:

```
/**
 * Изменить формат цены - вместо диапазона вывести "От: "
 *
 * @param float $price Цена товара.
 * @param object $product Товар.
 * @return string
 */
function variable_price_format_filter( $price, $product ) {
    $prefix = 'От: ';

    $min_price_regular = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $min_price_sale    = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
    $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );

    $price = ( $min_price_sale == $min_price_regular ) ?
        wc_price( $min_price_regular ) :
        '<del>' . wc_price( $min_price_regular ) . '</del>' . '<ins>' . wc_price( $min_price_sale ) . '</ins>';

    return ( $min_price == $max_price ) ?
        $price :
        $prefix . $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'variable_price_format_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variable_price_format_filter', 10, 2 );
```

[Работающий пример](http://test.kagg.eu/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B/quia-qui-atque-quia-magnam/) на моем тестовом сайте.